# how to get variable with regular expression from a response header in jmeter

Tags: jmeter, header, response

response header :

Content-Range: items=0-99/17
want to extract the value 17 from the above & use it as a jmeter variable in next requests.

I have tried couple of patterns like (the below mentioned)
[^^]+?
but not getting the matching response

Answer (score 0):

1. Add a [Regular Expression Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor) as a child of the request which returns the above header
2. Configure it as follows:

   [image]

   Textual version of the regular expression just in case:

   ```
   Content-Range: items=\d+-\d+/(\d+)
   ```
3. That's it, refer the extracted value as `${foo}` where required

Demo:

More information:

- [JMeter: Regular Expressions](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/regular_expressions.html)
- [Using RegEx (Regular Expression Extractor) with JMeter](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207421325-Using-RegEx-Regular-Expression-Extractor-with-JMeter)